# Which full suspension bike is this?

Tags: mountain-bike, identify-this-bike

I got this for $10 from my neighbor, who had it laying around for years. As you can see, the rear shock is gone, but the rest is there. It doesn't have any marks or model name, only a serial number at the bottom. It has Shimano Deore and Tranz X parts.

Can someone tell me which bike this might be, just by looking at the picture?

[image: Y-frame single-pivot mountain bike]

Comment: Thanks for the info , I've been looking like crazy but cannot find anything similar. I even tried searching mercedez Benz bike because of the emblem looking part on the bike . What I found out that it could be a downhill bike but who knows .

Comment: Can I ask what country you're in? The square tubes of the rear pivot remind me of some PRC bikes I saw in the late 90s. I'd also be interested in the material or weight, if you know it.

Comment: I'm in the  US , las Vegas NV to be exact . I'm not sure about the material but it weights 25lbs as it is right now . I noticed this are the components  Joy tech hubs, (wheels) ,Shimano STX RC,RITCHEY PROLITE BAR, TRANZ X stem, TEKTRO brakes..DEORE LX, Shimano A crank set.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I believe it's based on a 90's Trek Y-33 with some heavy modifications or maybe a wanna-be bike.
But I would stake a claim that's it came out around the time the Trek Y was popular.

Someone perhaps had field day welding it? Or it's just a replicated design.
This image is a random Trek Y image.

[image]

Comment: More pics: https://cool386.com/trek/trek.htm

Comment: Nice bike - its a similar overall design, but OP's is definitely different.  The location of the pivot is substantially different, and the trek has roughly equal sized downtube and toptube (naming?!)  where OP's is a box-section main with the seat support top-tube added)   Similar but not the same .

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you for all the info !  I started the restoration, rims are impeccable straight, will keep looking see if I find a similar bike and let you guys know hopefully . Thank you!!

Comment: It's probably a copy cat. i mentioned that in my answer, but it surely was the inspiration! I rephrased a bit to state more so it could be a copy cat.

Answer (score 4):

Fairly common late 1990's 'copy' of the original Specialized FSR Stump jumper, using a single pivot rather than the Horst link Specialized used (which was patented back then). Several manufacturers toyed with this 'kinds a motorbike' frame design before falling back to more traditional 'tubes' design. Weight was always a problem as soon as you moved away from a triangle and had cantilevers with open ends or solid beams instead of rear triangle. Great thing about that era was frame designers were 'brave enough to be different' and so were consumers.

Shimano Deore indicates either a reasonable quality bike or it has been upgraded. Deore (on its own) was re-introduced as a name in 1999 with 9 speed.

Beyond that, it's not really possible to know the brand. Popular brands in your area, along with the front fork, could be used to trawl though the internet and find a likely match, but while I hold out hope we can help, I suspect finding the make/medel/brand will not be successful.

As far as the bike goes, based on year 2000+/-, best guess is Dual crown forks and Deore indicate it was probably built and marketed as a downhill bike.  Single Pivot did not make great XC bikes back then with the shocks they had available. Deore quality indicates it is not a BSO from Walmart.  Without actually inspecting the bike this is mostly speculation though.

Comment: Hello again friends!!! I was able to service the bike myself , I stalled new cables , brakes and shifters , bleed the disc brakes , lubed chainrings , cleaned chain , crown shocks , ( no rear shock yet) ..I just need rear shock and tires .  Also here is the serial # if anybody can spot the brand or model by this info.  Serial # MT90400522. Ty!

Comment: Shocks are measured in length and stroke. You need the match these (and ideally other parameters). Best to ask another question for a detailed response as the answer is too long for comments (and OT for the original question).

Answer (score 1):

Clearly the old shock was removed and replaced with a rigid link.  Maybe the original failed, or maybe the frame design would bob unpleasantly while pedalling.  Assuming the bolts are secure, this mod should be safe to ride.  Effectively this is making the bike into an extra-heavy rigid frame.

Is the white paint original?  Seems to go up the seat post suggesting not.

The dual-crown shocks on the front look like motorbike styling, do they actually move?

Disk brake front and rim brake rear is an interesting choice - that suggests it's not a BSO.

Clearly the saddle is a replacement, and the chain has been there for a long time.  A clean and service, new brake pads and it should be good for a test ride.   Enjoy your new bike !

Comment: Thanks for the info! The white paint not the original, the red and yellow seems they are original paint . As for the dual crown shocks they do work!